# Fire react "onMouseMove" event when css "pointer-events-none" is set

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I have a React Component with an `absolute` positioned `div` which overlays other content in my application. The `div` is used to fire react's `onMouseMove` event.

I want to set the css value `pointer-events-none` so all components underneath the `div` are still clickable, have pointer events etc. Whatever when `pointer-events-none` is present, the `onMouseMove` event will not fire anymore. Everything should behave like the overlay `div` is not present, it should just fire `onMouseMove`.

The code structure looks like this:

```
<button>I should be clickable</button>
<div>
  <div
    style={{
      opacity: 0,
      position: `absolute`,
      top: `50px`,
      left: `50px`,
      width: `30vw`,
      height: `30vh`,
      pointerEvents: `none`,
    }}
    onMouseMove={() => {
      console.log(`Fire!`)
    }}
  >
    Overlay
  </div>
  <button>I should be clickable</button>
  <a>I should be clickabel</a>
</div>
<button>I should be clickable</button>
```

I think I'm missing something or have chosen a completely wrong path here.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Wrong logic imho. Remove pointer events none if you want a mouse event on it... Try playing with z-index

Comment: Changing the z-index doesn't solve the problem. Either "onMouseMove" doesn't fire ore the  content underneath is not clickable anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to place overlay div at the root (in such case events will propagate), remove pointerEvents rule and opacity so that the content inside div would be visible:

```
<div
  style={{
    position: `absolute`,
    top: `50px`,
    left: `50px`,
    width: `30vw`,
    height: `30vh`
  }}
  onMouseMove={() => {
    console.log(`Fire!`)
  }}
>
  <button>I should be clickable</button>
  <button>I should be clickable</button>
  <a>I should be clickable</a>
  <button>I should be clickable</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works fine for the content within this component. When the component is placed somewhere else on my page and it overlays another button, that button won't be clickable anymore. I think what im trying to achieve is impossible.